# Someone keeps rejecting my edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I tried to edit this answer:

[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805587/1369235)

(mentioned about sortUsingFunction:context:).

However, each time I finished the edit, user Jeroen Moons (not the author of original answer) rejected my edit, and added an extra space in the original answer, and made the edit himself.

I am not sure if there is something wrong  in my edit (I did not get any sort of message, or any comment in his edit). So may I know what's actually going on here? Or is there anyway I could check my mistake?

The two rejected edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/682859
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/682943

Comment: You mean [rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/682943) your edits. I don't see them in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/805587/revisions).

Comment: @Lix Yes (see my edit on the question)

Comment: Not speaking for anyone else, but first, the two edits you have linked to are borderline (don't add much), and second, you spelled "you" as "u". That could easily get me to hit the "reject" button.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're confused on how suggested edits work...and so seems to be Jeroen Moons.

Jeroen edited your suggested edit and unchecked the "Helpful" checkbox to mark that the suggested edit was not helpful, but that there was still something to edit. Despite that, it looks more like Jeroen should have rejected it right away, instead of editing your edit and removing your changes.

Also, your edit did not really add anything of value, and should have been rejected as "too minor".

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Actually I added the 'sample call' because when I read the answer, I am not quite sure if the second parameter of context could be set to nil. I checked the official documentation and tried out, and confirmed it's ok. Also, I think it's a little tricky that the user should not use @sel for the C method. So I think this edit could make the answer more clear for future readers of this post.

Comment: @Walty: I do not know Objective-C or any other thing about iOS, but it seems like *very* minor on how to call the method. If you feel there's something wrong with the original code, please leave a comment pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note here is that if some user reverts your edits, rather than starting an edit war and re-editing every time someone doesn't agree with your edit, ask the user why they feel your edit was invalid.

You can "ping" the editor of a post even though their name doesn't appear in the autocomplete feature. You can use normal [@ replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

The user who didn't agree with your edits has >2K reputation, so he has the [edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). In such cases where a more experienced (Stack Overflow) user decides against your proposals, you should definitely take a step back and listen to what they have to say.

I'm sure that id you approach this with an attitude to improve your efficiency and contribution to the site, people will be happy to nudge you in the right direction.

Sometimes people just wake up on the wrong side of the bed. Maybe they are in a bad mood or maybe they've been tearing their hair out over some phantom bug for the last 4 hours. Sometimes people make mistakes in their judgment and you have every right to voice your concern if you encounter such a case, option one is what I detailed above but in extreme cases you can always flag the post and write a custom message to the moderators explaining the situation. Remember that the moderators are not there to solve technical arguments about right or wrong code - they are there to make sure that everything is being handled in a fair and appropriate manner.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I just sent a reply to the editor. Honestly, I just want to know the reason, so that I would know how to improve the edit next time :) I am pretty sure most ppl are harmless here.